# php mysql select and count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have mysql table named 'tagtable' and it has text type column 'params' column like below;

```
id   tag                 params    //in text type 
1   #discount          {"activity":[105,106,107]}
2   #table             {"activity":[108,109,110,111]}
3   #pencil            {"activity":[112,113]}
4   #door              {"activity":[114]}
5   #phone             {"activity":[115]}
6   #wall              {"activity":[116,117,118,119,120]}
7   #radio             {"activity":[121,122,123]}
```

my expexted result is selecting top 4 tag with most activity number count from text type params column  and counting them, like below:

```
#wall-5  , #table-4 , #discount-3, #radio-3
```

How can I achieve that with php ?

Comment: What is the reason you don't store normalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
SELECT 
ID, 
tag, 
(CHAR_LENGTH(params) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(params, ',', '')) + 1) as total 
FROM tagtable 
order by total desc 
limit 4
```

Comment: Hello,I tried it but gives error to me " Call to a member function query() on boolean "

Comment: @askerman Please check this link. It's work perfectly. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oiHQEKQEQPHn8KXsPuRJme/2